# onclick radio button make textbox value null and hide textbox

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I want to calculate the amount
Eg: product cost
material
GST

So if i Enter product cost, material cost(uses radio button) and GST it will show the result but the issue is when i click on no option the cost steel added on the result . If i click on no radio button material cost will automatically reduce from total cost but its not happening
plz solve my problem
my code link is here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gbhw3u?file=src%2Findex.html

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [_How do I ask a good question?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Do your [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/6634591), [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt, as an [edit] to your question, and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that the function with the name "yesnoCheck" is not defined. you can define it and then try to call it in your HTML.

Comment: Its already define in index.html file that's why the ('yes' 'no') button is working